Comparing excel sheets with different formats
In B7 cell of "XYZ" sheet of Workbook 1, I have a dropdown with 50 states. In cell E5 of "ABC" sheet of Workbook 1, I have a dropdown of some numbers like 10, 20, 30 and so on. From cell X7 to X25 of "PQR" tab of Workbook 1, I have a list of numbers like 0, 1, 2 and so on. In corresponding cells in "PQR" tab of workbook 1 in column AD (i.e. AD7 to AD25), I have a values that get calculated based on the state value selected in XYZ, range selected in ABC and for a corresponding number in PQR in X column. AD has formula and takes state, and other values as inputs.
In Workbook 2, I have one sheet "LMN" which has 4 columns which have hardcoded these values. Column D in LMN has ranges with same options in ABC. Column E has states same as from XYZ sheet. Column F has options from column X in PQR. And column G has values from AD column in PQR.
Now, the values in AD column of Workbook 1 have changed. How can I compare the table in Workbook 1 vs the table in workbook 2



What are your screenshots showing and how are they different from each other? You haven't described the different formats very well
